# MVC - The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a MVC project and every time I try to click on "**About**" or "**Contact**" I get:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of the resource dependencies) could have been removed, the name may have
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Check the spelling of the URL
>   below is correct.
>
> Requested URL: /Views/Home/Contact.cshtml

I am able to get to the startpage(index) but once I try to redirect to anoter page like "About" or "Contact" I get the error message as I mentioned above.

Here is my code:

```
   <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="~/Views/Home/About.cshtml">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

My HomeController:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
```

[image: The File directory structure]

Comment: @JessicaPartridge Tried it, didn't work. I got the same error message.

Comment: Should also remove "views" as this is hidden

Comment: heymega suggested a better way of doing this though, you should be using @Html.ActionLink, this is how it's done in razor which is the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be linking to `cshtml` files. These files are meant to be rendered by the view engine. I believe you should be linking to your controller's actions which return your views.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is definately better way

Comment: Correct way to do it, but one slight error - they wanted the link text of the first link to be Home not Index.

Comment: Ohh I see. It was like that you mentioned by default, but I changed it. I guess I'll change it back. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the .cshtml and /view/ from the links:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Home/About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

In MVC your URLs point to *actions* not *pages*.

Answer (score 2):

You must have been working with web forms(.aspx) pages.
MVC does not work this way.
As in code you have specified 3 actions in HomeController. default MVC route is `/{controller}/{Action}/{other param}` so your code will become

```
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```